# include не выводит шаблон страниц

Tags: php, html, шаблоны, include

есть такой вот код веб-страницы. Суть в том, что при нажатии на ссылку из навбара вылетает ошибка 404 вместо отображения шаблона страницы из папки view. Случилось это при переезде на новый хостинг, помогите разобраться пожалуйста. пробовал в include прописывать ссылку полностью, но результат одинаков. 
код приведен ниже

```html
<?
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
session_start();
@$page=$_REQUEST['page'];
if(empty($page)) {$page = 'index';}
 
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
 
define("CATALOG", TRUE);
include ("config.php");
 
?>
 
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="zxx">
 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
 
    
 
 
</head>
 
<body>
   
    <div class="header-area header-sticky">
        <div class="header-area__desktop">
            
            <div class="header-navigation-area header-navigation-area--style2 position-relative">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 position-static">
                        <div class="header-navigation-container">
                            <!-- logo -->
                            <div class="logo">
                                <a href="index">
                                    <img src="assets/img/logo/logo-blue-dark.png" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="header-navigation-wrapper header-navigation-wrapper--style4">
                                <div class="header-navigation-wrapper--style3__left">
                                    <div class="header-navigation__nav header-navigation__nav--style5 position-static">
                                        <nav>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li><a href="index">HOME</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="about">ABOUT US</a></li>
                                                <li class="has-children has-children--multilevel-submenu">
                                                    <a href="#">OUR SERVICES</a>
                                                    <ul class="submenu">
                                                        <li><a href="assist">Assist</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="cross">Cross</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </li>
                                           
                                                <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </nav>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 
 
        
<?
if ($page == 'index') {
include ("header/main.php");
}
else {
include ("header/content.php");
}
?>      
 
 
<?
if ($page != 'index') {
    include ("view/{$page}.php");
}
 
if ($page == 'index') {
    include ("plugin/first.php");
    include ("plugin/about.php");   
}
 
elseif ($page == 'about') {
    include ("plugin/team.php");
}
?> 
 
 
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: @$page - это что за конструкция?

Comment: <a href="index">  - что за ссылка)

может там было что то вроде  <a href = "<?= $page ?>" , скорее всего на новом хостинге у вас нет доп. правил для обработки урлов ( nginx или апач)